# Forza Motorsport 4 AI damage

Tags: forza-motorsport-4

How do you set the AI's damage to simulation so they take damage like normal players? Me and my bro want to wreck AI's cars but they will just flip over and keep going.

Comment: Unfortunately, from what I can find, damage suffered by AI, is ineffective. Thus meaning, they cannot be damaged within a race.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AI uses the same assists you do, so if you have damage set to simulation, they will be as well. You can test this by running an endurance race(many laps) that eventually forces you to refuel. If you have simulation on, the AI will have to refuel as well.

It's difficult to tell damage because the AI is good at correcting it. For example, if they have a broken driveline, they won't start drifting off to the side like you would, they pretty much perfectly correct it (like you would eventually get used to it).

Comment: Is it possible to have them be on simulation and you be on cosmetic?

Comment: No, they match you.